# MKV file cluster size which is encoded?

Tags: c++, hex, ascii, webm, mkv

Element IDs (also called EBML IDs), beginning with the ID itself, followed by the Data Size.

Data size, in octets, is also coded with an UTF-8 like system.

How can I decode the data size in decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the below simple sample code in
https://github.com/wangf1978/DumpTS/blob/master/Matroska.h

```
static uint64_t UnpackUnsignedIntVal(CBitstream&bs, uint8_t max_octs = 8, bool unPackVal=true, uint8_t* pcbValLen=nullptr)
{
    uint8_t nLeadingZeros = 0;
    uint64_t u64Val = bs.GetByte();
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < max_octs; i++)
        if ((u64Val&(1ULL << (7 - i))) == 0)
            nLeadingZeros++;
        else
            break;

    if (nLeadingZeros >= max_octs)  // Unexpected
        return UINT64_MAX;

    if (unPackVal)
        u64Val &= ~(1 << (7 - nLeadingZeros));

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i<nLeadingZeros; i++)
        u64Val = (((uint64_t)u64Val) << 8) | (uint8_t)bs.GetBits(8);

    if (pcbValLen != nullptr)
        *pcbValLen = nLeadingZeros + 1;

    return u64Val;
}

virtual int Unpack(CBitstream& bs)
{
    // Read the element ID
    uint64_t u64Val = UnpackUnsignedIntVal(bs, 4, false);
    if (u64Val == UINT64_MAX)
        return -1;

    ID = (uint32_t)u64Val;

    if ((u64Val = UnpackUnsignedIntVal(bs)) == UINT64_MAX)
        return -1;

    Size = u64Val;

    //printf("ID: 0X%X, Size: %lld(0X%llX)\n", ID, Size, Size);

    return 0;
}
```